# How to find greatest digit in a number using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a function in Java that returns the greatest digit in a number using recursion.
I have managed to do it using two parameters, the number and greater digit.
Initially the greater digit parameter accepts value as 0.

```
static int getGreatestDigit(int num , int greater){
    if(num != 0){
        if(num %10 > greater){
           greater = num%10;
           num = num/10;
           return getGreatestDigit(num , greater);
        }else{
           num = num/10;
           return getGreatestDigit(num , greater);
        }
    }
    return greater;
}
```

I want to write same recursive function but with only one parameter that is number.
Like

```
int getGreatestDigit(int num){
 //code
}
```

I am stuck at logic. How to do that?

Comment: Unless you somehow store the current result in ``num`` itself, you cannot do that.

Comment: Yes you can! You need to check for the bigger digit between the current digit and the rest of the digits you have checked so far when returning from the trivial case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first call to `getGreatestDigit(num)` needs to keep track of the `greater` result.  Each recursive call to `getGreatestDigit(num)` will return the greatest digit in the part of the original number that it is tasked with scanning.  The very first invocation of `getGreatestDigit(num)` can compare the number it took with the greatest number returned from all recursive calls.

```
int getGreatestDigit(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    int lastNum = num % 10;
    int otherDigits = num / 10;
    int recursiveLastNum = getGreatestDigit(otherDigits);
    return Math.Max(lastNum, recursiveLastNum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static int getGreatestDigit(int num)
{
    return num == 0 ? 0 :
        Math.Max(num % 10, getGreatestDigit(num / 10));
}
```

So basically, you look at the least significant digit each time, comparing it against the maximum of the rest of the digits.

Comment: The key difference between this and OP's is that this is not tail-recursive. In Java, of course, it doesn't matter, and neither does it matter on any problem with max size 9; however as a practice in the FP paradigm I'd prefer an entry-point function with one param, calling into a recursive two-param function.

Comment: Feels like someone told the OP to change his tail recursive solution to one  that is not.  He already had a working solution.

Comment: @EricJ. He just needs a front end to his function.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Very true, although in cases like this (where the problem is very small) I--just like the person who told the OP to change to a single-argument `getGreatestDigit`--would prefer a simple function like this over a tail-recursive function like in the question.

Comment: But what I'm proposing would be exactly that: changing to a single-argument `getGreatestDigit`---just that it would have a private two-arg overload (the existing function). To an FP-trained eye that would actually be a more natural solution. In Clojure you wouldn't even need two functions, it would be a tail-recurnive idiom (`loop-recur`) inside the function body.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah yes, I guess I didn't read your first comment correctly. I would now say that I would prefer a simple function like mine over *2* functions any day, as long as the problem is as simple as this (and does not need to be optimized at all). I prefer readability and simplicity over efficiency as long as efficiency is not required.

Comment: Well, if this was _real_ code, then it would have a simple `for`-loop. Obviously it's for practice. But nevermind, enough idle chatting....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if you use the functions stack as temporary memory to hold your interim results, i.e. what was previously stored in the `greater` parameter.

This changes your function to be no longer tail recursive, making it worse performance wise.

```
int greatestDigit(int num) {
 int last = num % 10;
 int rest = num / 10;
 if (rest == 0) {
  return last;
 } else {
  int candidate = greatestDigit (rest);
  if (candidate > last) {
   return candidate;
  } else {
   return last;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Pseudocode:
1. if num > 9, /10 and call getGreatestDigit on that (recursive step). Then get the current digit (undivided) and return the greater of the two
2. if num <= 9, return num
*/

int getGreatestDigit(int num){
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Biggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Number");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        int big=getBiggest(n,n%10);
        System.out.println("Biggest digit in "+n+" is : " +big);
    }

private static int getBiggest(int n,int big) {//take big=n%10 in method caller
        
        if(n!=0)
            
        if(n%10>big) {
            big=n%10;
            n=n/10;
            return getBiggest(n,big);
        }
        else 
        {
          n=n/10;
          return getBiggest(n,big);
        }
         return big;
    }
     
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
    package Map;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class Practice8 {
        public int highestDigit(int number){
            ArrayList<Integer> temp= new ArrayList<>();
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(number);
            String value= sb.toString();
            for(int i=0;i<value.length();i++){
                temp.add((int)value.charAt(i)-'0');
            }
            int max=0;
            for(int x: temp){
                 if(x>max){
                    max=x;
                }
            }
            return max;
    
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Practice8 practice8= new Practice8();
            System.out.println(practice8.highestDigit(379));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a function that takes a number as an argument and returns the highest digit in that number.
highestDigit(4666) ➞ 6
it's working fine. I am getting the highest no. using array

Comment: My question is how to find the greatest digit in a number by using recursion. Your code does not use recursion.